# SSD upgrade vs RAM upgrade?

Tags: memory

I have a Mid 2010 Mac Book Pro. It's now super slow. I am exploring upgrade options since I don't want to get a new laptop until end of college. My options are upgrading RAM to 8 GB from 4 GB or removing my SATA Hard Disk DVD Drive and putting SSD.

What would be better for performance? Any other options I am missing?

Comment: SSDs provide double the performance of a normal spinning disk, in my experience. If you can afford more RAM as well, do that too. More RAM is always better.

Comment: Without understanding why your MBP is slow and what you're trying to do with it, there's no way to give you useful advice about how to speed it up.

Comment: There's really no answer to this question other than: Upgrade both and get as much as money can buy you. Shopping recommendations are off topic as per the [FAQ] partly for these reasons, sorry. As @DavidSchwartz said, if you're able to identify a special bottleneck, the slowness could be due to anything.

Comment: For example, it could be slow because the CPU is overheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more ram is always a good thing, but the SSD is going to give you the most bang for your buck, really.

Answer (score 0):

More RAM or a faster disk will not speed-wise help if the MBP's installation is full of cruft.

My advice would be to make a full, bootable backup (TEST IT!) then re-install OS X and add the tools you need one by one.

Invest in SSD (first) or RAM (second) only if that doesn't help.

Another point to consider: An SSD is fast, but it will be smaller than your current HD.